how to make the latex support traditional-Chinese characters
Today I am using XeLaTeX to write some traditional (as opposed to simplified) Chinese characters or glyphs. This is a minimal demo:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
靜
\end{document}

the output is just an F. I have also tried like this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctex}

\begin{document}
靜
\end{document}

both did not work. Am I missing something? I am using xelatex, the version is texlive 2023. This is the log about version info:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023)


FandolSong-Regular is the default font and it obviously does not contain a glyph for 靜. But you can change the font by adding \setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC} for example.

I suggest you switch from your current xeCJK-based setup, which (a) employs the fontspec package implicitly and (b) imposes a default font choice that, as you've discovered, may not provide all needed glyphs, to loading fontspec directly and employing more suitable Opentype font families, such as Noto Serif TC and Noto Sans TC, which provide 8 or 9 separate font weights. Noto fonts, among other fonts, can be downloaded and used free of charge.
The following solution works with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

The very first time LuaLaTeX uses a specific OpenType font to compile a document, the compilation will be slow because the luaotfload utility, which runs in the background, has to build a detailed hash table. However, all subsequent compilation runs will be quick.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif TC} 
\setsansfont{Noto Sans TC}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newcommand\qbf{The quiet brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\begin{document}
靜 \qbf 

\sffamily
靜 \qbf
\end{document}


=) Nice adaptation of the example sentence to the meaning of the character.

@JasperHabicht - Thanks -- I was wondering if people might notice the word play. :-)

This answer suggests switching to luatex, which isn't a bad idea, but the posted code is valid for xetex as well. Also the brown fox sentence excercises the latin alphabet, I think you should have come up with a sentence to excercise the full cjk range instead:-)

@DavidCarlisle The example sentence does not cover the full latin alphabet either ...

@DavidCarlisle - The updated [!] sample sentence is missing the letters "c" and "k". :-) I'll update the answer to switch the focus from XeLaTeX vs LuaLaTeX toward xeCJK (with an implicit \setmainfont directive) vs a direct choice of the font (via the explicit \setmainfont and \setsansfont directives).

With ctex, set a traditional Chinese font with \setCJKmainfont.  Pick one that matches the width of your Latin font and load it with an appropriate Scale= option. Renderer=HarfBuzz was necessary in the past but might no longer be.  I see that luatexja, which is the backend for ctex on LuaTeX, does not recommend it.  You might optionally set up variations such as sans-serif, bold and slanted.
Here is an example requiring the (non-variable, OTF) Noto CJK fonts from Google:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} % Load New Computer Modern

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase, Renderer=HarfBuzz}
\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSerifCJKtc]{
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  Extension=.otf,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.15}
\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSansCJKtc]{
  UprightFont=*-Medium,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  Extension=.otf,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.15}

\setCJKmainfont{NotoSerifCJKtc}
\setCJKsansfont{NotoSansCJKtc}
% \setCJKmonofont or \setCJKfontfamily if needed.

\begin{document}
\noindent
靜 New Computer Modern Book \textbf{Bold 靜} \textit{Italic 靜} \\
\textsf{靜 New Computer Modern Sans \textbf{Bold 靜} \textit{Italic 靜}}
\end{document}


If you need only a few words or short phrases of traditional Chinese in a document primarily in a Western language, you could instead do something like:
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase, Renderer=HarfBuzz}
\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSerifCJKtc]{
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  Extension=.otf,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.15}
\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSansCJKtc]{
  UprightFont=*-Medium,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  Extension=.otf,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.15}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese-traditional}

\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{rm}
          {NotoSerifCJKtc}
\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{sf}
          {NotoSansCJKtc}


You need to select a font that supports traditional Chinese. Running XeLaTeX on your document produces
Missing character: There is no 靜 (U+975C) in font [FandolSong-Regular.otf]/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;!

On my system I found that STSong supports this glyph (and probably a large part of the entire traditional character set).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{STSong}

\begin{document}

靜

\end{document}



Using albatross I found TeXLive fontsHarano Aji Gothic, Harano Aji Mincho,  IPAMincho, IPAGothic but I think they are all Japanese fonts so not sure if convenient in original context.
